# Switching to Kotlin DSL Unresolved reference when trying to access other file

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have an error when trying to use Kotlin DSL for my gradle files.

In `build.gradle(app)` I have a function to retrieve an api key stored in an 
file `keys.properties`, the function in Groovy is the following:

```
// Retrieve key api
def getApiKey() {
    def keysFile = file("keys.properties")
    def keysProperties = new Properties()
    keysProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keysFile))
    def apiKey = keysProperties['API_KEY']
    return apiKey
}
```

When switching to Kotlin DSL I naively changed the function as follow:

```
// Retrieve key for TMDB api
fun getApiKey() {
    val keysFile = file("keys.properties")
    val keysProperties = Properties()
    keysProperties.load(FileInputStream(keysFile))
    val apiKey = keysProperties["API_KEY"]
    return apiKey
}
```

The build then returns the following error:

```
.../app/build.gradle.kts:13:26: Unresolved reference: Properties
```

Does anyone know how to fix that?

### Edit

as suggested by #bam bam, adding an import `import java.util.Properties` solved the problems.. But other problems came, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59053039/1286214)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

did you import class? add `import java.util.Properties` on top of your build.gradle.kts