# kotlin DSL retrieving keys from other file

Tags: android, kotlin, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am trying to switch my gradle files to Kotlin DSL. My project is making call 
to an API.

In `build.gradle(app)` I had a function to retrieve an api key stored in an other 
file `keys.properties`.

After some problem (for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59046413/switching-to-kotlin-dsl-unresolved-reference-when-trying-to-access-other-file)) I rewrote the function to get the 
key. I wrote the following function in `build.gradle.kts`:

```
import import java.io.File

fun readFileLineByLineUsingForEachLine2(fileName: String): HashMap<String, String>{
    val items = HashMap<String, String>()

    File(fileName).forEachLine {
        items[it.split("=")[0]] = it.split("=")[1]
    }

    return items
}
```

Then I set a variable to hold the value of a particular key:

```
buildConfigField(String!, "API_KEY", returnMapOfKeys()["API_KEY"])
```

After fixing some errors I am stuck with the following one:

```
app/build.gradle.kts:49:36: Expecting ')'
```

which point on the line above with `buildConfigField`.

Does someone know where is this error ?

Or does someone know how to retrieve keys from files with Kotlin DSL ?

Comment: Seems like it has nothing to do with the keys, but your code simply doesn't compile. Check your syntax around line 49

Answer (score 7):

I solved my problem (it seems so.. **check the edit!!**). I ended up with the following function:

```
// Retrieve key for api
fun getApiKey(): String {
    val items = HashMap<String, String>()
    val f = File("keys.properties")

    f.forEachLine {
        items[it.split("=")[0]] = it.split("=")[1]
    }

    return items["API_KEY"]!!
}
```

And then I call `buildConfigField` as follow:

```
buildConfigField("String", "API_KEY", getApiKey())
```

There are no errors anymore on this part.

### Edit

Once I have fixed all errors in the `build.gradle.kts`, the build of my project return that the file `keys.properties` could not be found: I had to fix my function `getApiKey`. Finally I could build and run my project with the following implementation:

```
// Return value of api key stored in `app/keys.properties`
fun getApiKey(): String {
    val items = HashMap<String, String>()

    val fl = rootProject.file("app/keys.properties")

    (fl.exists())?.let {
        fl.forEachLine {
            items[it.split("=")[0]] = it.split("=")[1]
        }
    }

    return items["API_KEY"]!!
}
```

This function is far to be good with all its hardcoded stuff but it allows to build my project.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative

```
import com.android.build.gradle.internal.cxx.configure.gradleLocalProperties

val apiKey = gradleLocalProperties(rootDir).getProperty("key.properties")
```

..

```
buildConfigField("String", "API_KEY", "\"$apiKey\"")
```

Answer (score 2):

In your kts file, first import

```
import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.io.FileNotFoundException
import java.util.Properties
```

then you can do this:

```
fun getApiKey(): String {
    val fl = rootProject.file("gradle.properties") <- the path for the file where your key is.

    if (fl.exists()) {
        val properties = Properties()
        properties.load(FileInputStream(fl))
        return properties.getProperty("API_KEY") <- the name your give to it
    } else {
        throw FileNotFoundException()
    }
}
```

Now you call use it:  `buildConfigField("String", "API_KEY", getApiKey())`

Answer (score 0):

buildConfigField("String", "APIKEY",project.properties["MY_KEY"].toString())

buildFeatures {
buildConfig = true }